# Minimize SCSS to CSS with webpack keeping file/folder structure

Tags: css, webpack, sass, mini-css-extract-plugin

I am having trouble understanding how to compile and minify my scss files to css, while keeping the same folder and file structure.  I am using MiniCssExtractPlugin to extract everything, as well as style-loader, css-loader, postcss-loader, and sass-loader

Here is the file structure in my src folder

[image]

`app.scss` contains all the imports.  importing from folders 1-7.  I am first having trouble with the imports, and then have trouble compiling and minimizing the remaining scss files.

The end goal is to have an compiled folder look like this with each file being minimized and app.scss bundle all the imports

[image]

Here is a run down of the code I have so far for webpack.config.js

```
plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: 'css/[name].css',
            chunkFilename: '[id].css'
        })
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    { loader: 'css-loader', options: { sourceMap: true } },
                    { loader: 'postcss-loader', options: { sourceMap: true } },
                    { loader: 'sass-loader', options: { sourceMap: true } },
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [new TerserJSPlugin({extractComments: false}), ],
        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                vendor: {
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/](lodash)[\\/]/,
                    name: 'vendors',
                    chunks: 'all',
                },
            },
        },
    },
```

When running this code, I just get an app.css file under a css folder that does not have imports included, and no other files are included as well.  Can someone help my understand the process I need to take?  I've been all over docs for each loader and not really understanding what I am looking for.

Thanks!